# Switch Configuration - Change the trunk allow VLAN

Tags: switch, trunk

May i know any service interruption if i issue the command on changing the trunk allowed vlan on both end:

switchport trunk allowed vlan 10, 20, 30 to switchport trunk allow vlan 10, 20, 30, 40

Comment: Please specify the switch brand, model and software version, as this could have an impact on the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest using the `add` option: `switchport trunk allowed vlan add 40`.

In addition to reducing the risk of operator error, it should ensure that there's no service interruption for the already allowed VLANs (not likely, but may depend on switch model and firmware version).

As Marc has pointed out below, trying to use the `add` option but then actually forgetting to include the magic keyword is a very painful experience - do take care. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ah yes,  forgetting the `add` in `trunk allowed vlan add NNN`.  The one baptism-of-fire mistake *every* network admin has to make once in his career. :-D